# Deselect/Unfocus input field using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery Unfocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857245/jquery-unfocus)

Is there a way to deselect/unfocus an input field using JQuery? Something like `$("input#name").select().focus();` but in reverse?

Comment: Use blur(); to defocus your control

Comment: `.blur()` is the method you want...

Comment: Form consists of one input field, tried adding one then hiding it but didn't work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251547/force-an-event-in-jquery

Comment: @michael I thought I tried $("input#name").blur(); and it didn't work, tried again and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

.blur();

reference: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

> *Bind an event handler to the "blur" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.*
>
> ...This method is a shortcut for... `.trigger( "blur" )`...
>
> The `blur` event is sent to an element when it loses focus. Originally, this event was only applicable to form elements, such as `<input>`. In recent browsers, the domain of the event has been extended to include all element types. An element can lose focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks elsewhere on the page...

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [blur method from jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

So it would be:

```
$('input').blur();
```

Hope it was useful !